# Why I can not get property of object ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have this code and I am trying to pass variable into JSX into render section of the React Js Script. I have an error `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

Why if I have this property in the object?

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    blogs: []
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  const blogss = [
    {
      title: "Всемогущая функция Query — подробное руководство",
      author: 1,
      viewers: 213
    },
    {
      title: "Всемогущая функция Query — подробное руководство",
      author: 1,
      viewers: 213
    }
  ];
  this.setState(() => ({ blogs: blogss }));
}

render() {
  const { blogs } = this.state;
  return <h1>{blogs[0].title}</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state array is called `blogs`, but you are destructuring `obj` in the render method.

Since `blogs[0]` will be `undefined` for the initial render, you need to check that it is set before you try to access the `title` property from it.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    blogs: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      blogs: [
        {
          title: "Всемогущая функция Query — подробное руководство",
          author: 1,
          viewers: 213
        },
        {
          title: "Всемогущая функция Query — подробное руководство",
          author: 1,
          viewers: 213
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { blogs } = this.state;

    return <h1>{blogs[0] && blogs[0].title}</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working! I wonder what the issue was? Please check this code snippet!

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const blogs = [{
        "title": "Всемогущая функция Query — подробное руководство",
        "author": 1,
        "viewers": 213
      },
      {
        "title": "Всемогущая функция Query — подробное руководство",
        "author": 1,
        "viewers": 213
      }
    ]

    return (

      <
      h1 > {
        blogs[0].title
      } <
      /h1>
    )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Please take a look on the edited task I have this array of object not in render section

Answer (score 0):

The `render` method is called the first time right after mounting, before `componentDidMount`. Therefore it will try to read `blogs[0].title` from the initial state which doesn't have any elements. I advise that you restructure your render to look something like:

```
return <h1>{blogs[0] && blogs[0].title}</h1>;
```

Additionally, in case that you would need the whole array later on, you can do something similar to this:

```
return blogs.map((elem) => <h1 key={elem.title}>elem.title</h1>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the question mark after `blogs[0]`. It works for me.

Do:

```
<h1>{blogs[0]?.title}</h1>;
```

instead of:

```
<h1>{blogs[0].title}</h1>;
```